# Flat List gets hidden once the state gets changed in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am having a FlatList view with checkbox for each item.when i press a checkbox the state gets changed from false to true at that time the list gets hidden.Does anyone has come through this strange behaviour.

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.branches}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    { tempCheckValues[item._id] = false; }
    return (
      <ListItem avatar key={item._id}>
        <Left>
          <CheckBox
            checked={item.checked}
            onPress={this.toggleCheckbox.bind(this, item._id)}
          />
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Text>{item.branch_name}</Text>
          <Text note>{item.formatted_address}</Text>
        </Body>
      </ListItem>
    );
  }
  }
/>
```

Check Box Toggle:

```
toggleCheckbox = (id) => {
  const changedCheckbox = this.state.branches.find((branch) => branch._id === id);
  console.log('changedCheckbox', changedCheckbox);
  changedCheckbox.checked = !changedCheckbox.checked;
  const checkboxes = Object.assign({}, this.state.checkboxes, changedCheckbox);
  this.setState({ branches: checkboxes });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the state can be the reason for the problem. It would better to clone the branches state and update the cloned branches and finally setState.

```js
const clonedBranches = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.branches));
const updatedBranch = clonedBranches.find(({_id}) => _id === id)
updatedBranch=!updatedBranches.checked;
this.setState({branches: clonedBranches})
```

Comment: updatedbranches is clone of all branches of state.   updated Branch is the branch for the changedCheckbox is called.

Answer (score 0):

inside toggleCheckbox

```
this.setState({ branches: checkboxes });
```

but you are getting data in FlatList with branches

```
 <FlatList
  data={this.state.branches}
```

When you call toggleCheckbox,  branches array is updated.
Got it?